# Calculate distance between 2 access points

Tags: gps, wifi, distance

I have 2 portable access points (mobile hotspots). I want to know the exact distance between them by using wifi strength (db). Is it possible to get accuracy in centimetres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is usually called RSSI-based WIFI indoor positioning. Recently, AI is used to improve the accuracy, meanwhile, it's still hard to get accuracy in centimeters in this way.

Last year, Google Android tried to achieve 1 meter accuracy, and Wifi RTT (round time trip) (or called FTM (fine time measurement) or 802.11mc) is used for this.

https://www.gpsworld.com/how-to-achieve-1-meter-accuracy-in-android/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vywGgSrGODU

https://source.android.google.cn/devices/tech/connect/wifi-rtt

FYI.